# Retrieve command on developer org throwing error "ERROR running force:source:retrieve: Cannot read property 'record' of undefined"

Tags: salesforcedx

I am trying to retrieve data(aura components,apex classes) from salesforce nonscratch org(developer org). First I created the project, It worked fine then I authorized org that too worked fine but when Retrieve command is executed - its throwing error "ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  Cannot read property 'record' of undefined". Please help.

Comment: Standard things here: Have you tried sfdx update? Have you checked the logs with `tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log` for errors? What errors do you see?

Answer (score 1):

Same here but being in the mac/unix realm the workaround didn't work for me.
So my only solution so far is to downgrade the sfdx cli core pluggin :

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@49.5.0
```

Replacing the current salesforcedx@49.7.0 as the log ({HOME_DIR}/.sfdx/sfdx.log) showed me that sfdx-cli is looking for a project definition file ({HOME_DIR}/.sfdx/sfdx-project.json) at the {HOME_DIR} level, disregarding the current project config files. Idem for the [previous versions (49.6.1)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/salesforcedx).

Also note that that the [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/577) has just reached the [forcedotcom/cli](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli) team. I presume we now wait for a resolution in the next updates.

Comment: Thank you Eric S. I just did "sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@49.5.0" and it's working now. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Same is happening to me.

When I right click package.xml --> "SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org" I get the same error: "ERROR running force:source:retrieve: Cannot read property 'record' of undefined".

I'm using version "sfdx-cli/7.71.0-4193fb4acc win32-x64 node-v12.18.3"

As a workaround, you can execute the command in the terminal tab

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest "drive\:path_to_manifest\package.xml"
```

(Note the double quotes). Everything else seems to be working.

I'm unsure if this is a bug with the VS Salesforce Extension or Salesforce CLI.

Comment: Same here w/latest sfdx version as of 2/2/22 ... very annoying!